# Customer save after Observer called Multiple times

Tags: event-observer, magento2.3.3

I have an observe running after customer is saved, event used is customer_save_after which is working fine when trying to create a customer from front end, but when I create a customer from backend, the same observer is called 3 times, can anyone highlight why this is happening and how I can debug this that why its called multiple times.

Comment: Kindly check that same event call by other extension or what?

Comment: though its not the case, and even if other extensions are calling the same event, it wont make my code running multiple times, as I mentioned my code is running multiple times only when creating customer via admin, not when doing the same via front end.

Comment: customer_address_save_after is triggering multiple times in Magento ver. 2.4.2-p2. Any idea on why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

All I could think of are post-processing actions that occur in backend and don't in frontend, maybe some customizations on the admin area, some plugins that perform other saves or other observers.

As for how to debug this, I would recommend using xdebug and setting a breakpoint in the observer and check the trace window, maybe you can catch the subsequent calls made until the observer was engaged.

Also you could use blackfire to see the calls graph and check which class(es) trigger the subsequent observer call.

Comment: customer_address_save_after is triggering multiple times in Magento ver. 2.4.2-p2. Any idea on why this is happening?